# How to move windows server 2003 Licenee to one machine to another machine

Tags: windows

I have to buy a new server machine without Windows pre-installed. I have one server running Windows Server 2003 and I want to move all the license information from this old server machine to my new server machine. Once I done I will deactivate my old server.

Comment: This all depends on the licensing model the original server was licensed with. If the old server had an OEM version of Windows, there's **nothing** you can do to transfer it.

Answer (score -1):

?

- Install new Server
- Turn old server off.

Finished.

What is your problem?

Comment: Pert answer there! You could even turn off the old server before installing the new one...